# Redirecionamento - URL Amigável .HTACCESS

Tags: htaccess, url-amigavel

Eu criei um redirecionamento de um domínio para uma subpasta, vejam como ficou:

```
# Redirect from www to non-www location
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.meusite.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.meusite.com.br/loja/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Funcionou perfeitamente!

O problema é que preciso acessar uma outra subpasta, que é `www.meusite.com.br/administrar`, porém ao entrar sou redirecionado para `www.meusite.com.br/loja/administrar`

Alguma sugestão ?

Answer (score -1):

Consegui uma solução, veja abaixo:

```
# REDIRECT LOJA
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrar/ [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) http://meusite.com.br/loja/ [R=301,L] 
</ifmodule>
```